TV show about a guy who can live forever
I went to a friend's place. There was this show that was on about a guy that once he dies, he wakes up in the ocean. I really liked it but I don't know the name. I would have asked my friend if she wasn't so uptight. Any help, please?

We treat our friends better here. :) This sounds like the new ABC show Forever. From Wiki:

Dr. Henry Morgan (Ioan Gruffudd) is a New York City medical examiner who studies the dead for criminal cases and to solve the mystery of his own immortality. Since his first death 200 years ago as a doctor in the African slave trade, whenever he dies Morgan and his clothes disappear almost immediately, and he returns to life a few hours later in a nearby body of water naked with no memory of the intervening time.

Here's the teaser:




Too bad it was canceled. It was a good one.
